# If an assertion fails in a Geb test, how to keep the browser window open?

Tags: selenium, selenium-webdriver, geb

If a Geb test fails, it would be nice to inspect the page with a browser's developer tools. Is it possible to configure Geb in a way, that it stops on failure but keep the browser window open?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

From http://www.gebish.org/manual/current/configuration.html:

> **7.2.3 Driver Caching**
>
> ...
>
> Also, by default Geb will register a shutdown hook to quit any cached
>   browsers when the JVM exits. You can disable this by setting te config
>   property quitCachedDriverOnShutdown to false.

I so tried set do that in `GebConfig.groovy`:

```
quitCachedDriverOnShutdown = false
```

And that keeps the browser open even after all tests are finished or one has failed.